# Tool for diagnosing memory leaks in .NET (ASP.NET Application)

Tags: .net, asp.net, memory-leaks

we need a tool to detect easily memory leaks in an ASP.NET Application. We have an application, which consumes lot of memory.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Using [WinDbg](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx) is not as easy as using dotTrace but it can help you to discover lots of oddities in your application. Other than that you can find invaluable information about debugging ASP.Net applications on Tess Ferrandez's [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/).

Comment: +1 for Tess's Blog - Saw her present at Tech.Ed - she really knows her stuff, and her blog is full of useful tips on tracking down issues in ASP.NET applications

Comment: And she is going to prepare a new lab set :)

Answer (score 4):

Rob Mariani wrote a nice article on [Tracking down managed memory leaks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ricom/tracking-down-managed-memory-leaks-how-to-find-a-gc-leak) which helped me track down the dangling references in a desktop application.

Answer (score 4):

I have published a [new article on the subject on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658248.aspx). It contains a list of tools.

Comment: I think I know the screens used in the custom tools section.
We worked on the same product :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, "easily" is the trick... however [dotTRACE](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) might be worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

check out Microsoft's [FxCop](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9AEAA970-F281-4FB0-ABA1-D59D7ED09772&displaylang=en) which also analyzes performance issues, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[.Net Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/).  Used the trial version once. It was helpful, but I don't need it often enough to warrant buying one.

The thing I found was to ALWAYS make sure you dispose of any resources, particularly in DirectoryServices, that implement IDisposable.

Comment: Actually, don't try to dispose disposable static resources such as Brushes.Black if you intend to use them again :) Learned that the hard way...

Answer (score 0):

I read about [Ants Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_profiler/index.htm). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Read Tess at [If broken it is, fix it you should](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/). It should get you on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

I found this one quite useful too: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19490/Memory-Leak-Detection-in-NET

Summary of the interesting points:

1. Use Perfmon to monitor .Net CLR Locks/# of current logic threads to see if you are creating threads but not destroying them.
2. Use Perfmon to compare .Net CLR/# Bytes vs. Process/Private bytes to see if it is managed or unmanaged memory that is leaking
3. Assuming its managed memory that is leaking, using windbg/sos.dll to track down the references