# Unhandled .Net Framework exception occuring when threading

Tags: asp.net, caching, error-handling, visual-studio-2012, runtime

I am working on an asp.net website. I have large amounts of data (around 20 millions) and need to cache them in order to query and display data faster in my website. I am using threads to do it but after visiting some pages on my local machine I get this error: 
[image: Unhandled .net framework exception w3wp.exe]

How can I avoid this error or what are things I need to check?

Comment: Find the exception message in Event Viewer. This screenshot shows nothing that can be used to determine the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Change the unhandled exception policy back to the default behavior that occurs in the .NET Framework 1.1 and in the .NET Framework 1.0.

Note We do not recommend that you change the default behavior. If you ignore exceptions, the application may leak resources and abandon locks.

To enable this default behavior, add the following code to the `Aspnet.config` file that is located in the following folder:

**`%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727`**

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="true" />
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Took from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911816)

(Or) Try using Debug Diagnostic Tool to resolve your issue. Here is the link:-

[Tool for diagnosing memory leaks in .NET (ASP.NET Application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473760/tool-for-diagnosing-memory-leaks-in-net-asp-net-application)

Also I found a nice article about memory leaks, go through this article and see that if there is something wrong with your code:-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163491.aspx